# HTML5 custom data attributes in Drupal

Tags: javascript

I want to use the ["data" attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in some of my tags, and I have been searching for a way to include it.

For Example: I am adding JavaScript code to my form. I use `hook_form_alter()` and the `#attached` property.

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
$form['#attached']['js'][] = array('data' => $path . '/js/custom_values.js','type' => 'file');
```

How do I add a "data" attribute to the `<script>` tag generated? I want to use it for arguments to the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean how to add the `data-` attribute to the `<form>` tag it would be as easy as this:

```
$form['#attributes']['data-foo'] = 'bar';
```

The same goes for any element within the form:

```
$form['foo']['#attributes']['data-bar'] = 'baz';
```

For more info have a look at the [documentation for `#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes).

Comment: looks perfect! I will test it out